# Google docs viewer url parameters

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

Is there any sort of documentation on exactly what parameters you can put in the url of Google viewer?

Originally, I thought it was just url,embedded,chrome, but I've recently come accross other funny ones like a,pagenumber, and a few others for authentication etc.

Any clues?

Comment: I can't seem to find any information on the url paramaters apart from what I've already listed...

Comment: There are some at https://learninginhand.com/blog/google-document-url-tricks

Answer (score 3):

One I know is "chrome"

If you've got https://docs.google.com/viewer?........;chrome=true

then you see a fairly heavy UI version of that doc, however with "chrome=false" you get a compact version.

But indeed, I'd like a complete list myself!

Comment: I opened a forum question with Google over my momentary motivation for this, maybe go there and make your own, or help bump mine up: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=5a53860eaa63a0b7&hl=en

Answer (score 3):

> I'm also on a quest to discover some of the parameters of the viewer.
>   the "chrome" parameter doesn't seem to do anything, though. Is this
>   supposed to be the same as embedded=true?
>
> Parameters I know of:
>
> url= (obviously)
>   embedded= (obviously)
>   hl= set language of UI (tooltips)
>   #:0.page.1 = jump to page 2 (page 1 is numbered 0) - this is unreliable and often requires a refresh after the first load,
>   defeating the purpose.
>
> That said, when I use the Google Docs viewer on my site, "fit page to
>   screen" is the default view without any parameters. So maybe I'm
>   misunderstanding your question.

<sub>Source: For convenience, this is a full quote of the sole [answer](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/KjTq-Jwy3o8/10hfjZObqmoJ) (it is from user [k3david](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!profile/docs/APn2wQfZVUwG4obZBzaYZepLKT45-Gt4pKY5X5yK9ZT9SeHENUWmRzo3-YiitVSaJKdsCY6GbWGT)) to the [crosspost](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=5a53860eaa63a0b7&hl=en) of this question @Doc has posted to the Google support forum in 2011.</sub>

Comment: that hl parameter saved the day

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is very old and perhaps you already solved your issue, but for anyone on the internet who might be looking for an answer...

I have been looking for this recently, following a guide I found on GitHub Gist

https://gist.github.com/tzmartin/1cf85dc3d975f94cfddc04bc0dd399be

More specifically, the option to embed a certain page of pdf using

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?srcid=[put your file id here]&pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true" width="580px" height="480px"></iframe>
```

The best I could fing was this article (I suppose from a long time now)

https://weekly-geekly.github.io/articles/111647/index.html

---

**HOWEVER**, I tried modifying the attributes and the result was simply a redirect to

- `https://drive.google.com/file/d/[ID]/edit`
- `https://drive.google.com/file/d/[ID]/preview` or
- `https://drive.google.com/file/d/[ID]/view`

**AS OF MAY 2020, THIS SOLUTION PROBABLY DOESN'T WORK**

Comment: weekly-geekly ain't online anymore but repo's still available: https://github.com/BlancLoup/weekly-geekly.github.io/blob/master/articles/111647/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can pass q=whatever to pass a search query to the viewer.