# Default Zoom for Google Doc Embedder Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, google-drive-api

I am using the [Google Doc Embedder Wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-document-embedder/) to display PDFs on a website. There are no options that I can find (or documentation) to control the default zoom level.

Is there a way to programmatically configure the default zoom level, or override some JavaScript?

Here is the shortcode:

```
[gview file="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Cover-Story-1411.pdf"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's not possible and, if it is possible, my research shows no trace of Google's documentation about it. Also:

- tried adding the queries `&zoom=2` and `&z=2` in Google's Viewer URL, but to no avail.
- tried [this search query](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-drive%5D%20viewer%20is:q) at Web Applications but nothing showed up.
- checked the [mentioned plugin code](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/google-document-embedder/tags/2.5.13/gviewer.php#L91) and there's nothing about this in it.
- found this related and unsolved question here at SO: [Google docs viewer url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4917519/1287812).

I found some minor tweaks. The one for removing the sidebar makes the page occupy the full width:

- how to show only one page, from [Link to specific page on Google Document Viewer on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12290148/1287812).
- set the language used in tooltips adding the query var `&hl=pt_BR` (Brazilian Portuguese in this example), from this [Google forum thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/docs/how-do-i/KjTq-Jwy3o8).
- Remove the sidebar, from a Google forums thread as shown in [Can Google Viewer hide the lefthand navigation on a PDF by default](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/50773/22453)

Overriding with JavaScript [is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663118/1287812), as it will produce a SameOrigin security error.