# Google Docs Zoom Querystring Parameter

Tags: google-docs

Is there a way to set the zoom level in google docs by using a querystring parameter?

eg- https://docs.google.com/a/getsatisfaction.com/document/d/q3ljkasdlfgkjsdflgkj/edit?zoom=fit

I know there's other querystring parameters you can set, like how "render mode" can be set with the rm parameter (eg - rm=demo). I also found [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917519/google-docs-viewer-url-parameters), which doesn't mention zoom options.

Answer (score 3):

I have been searching for a while now and have not found any concrete way to manipulate the user's view setting of a document when it's embedded into a webpage via iframe. The only options I have found for getting a doc to adjust within the given frame are as follows:

/pub? - This removes any toolbar display and displays a rough view of the doc. If you use tabs or spaces to line things up, they will not look pretty with this option. I have tried adding the "rm=full" and/or "ui=2" parameters (and other combinations) but those did not do anything.

/preview? - This also removes any ui elements and just straight-up shows the doc. This one doesn't work for me because I need users to be able to print the doc.

I even thought that perhaps the view setting was determined in the doc itself, but anything I tried in that direction (setting to Fit, looking in doc settings, etc) produced no results. So the parameters I am using now are:

/edit?usp=viewing&chrome=false&rm=demo  (still overflows in the iframe in Firefox & Chrome)

I hope this info helps anyone else at least a little bit. (I would have provided all this as a comment but I needed more points in order to do that.) It's disappointing that one of the most obvious and relied-upon Docs options cannot be adjusted through parameters.

Comment: This might be useful information, but it doesn't appear to be relevant to the question.

Comment: My interpretation was the user was trying to set the zoom level of a document by using parameters in the url. In my case I'm trying to embed a Google doc and control the view settings in the url. I have been researching this for the past two days and have found very little information other than numerous versions of the same questions that are not answered. I figured this question specifically referenced zoom so I might as well post what I learned. And, being the very first time I have posted here, I suppose it's expected that I did it wrong in some way. :-) But thank you for the feedback. :-)

Comment: I do agree that the information is useful, but doesn't directly answer the question. Probably a good idea to leave it up though in case someone else lands on this page.

Comment: +1 for keeping this, I had the same specific question & while it's true this answer isn't perfect, it addresses similar issue. In particular, knowing the "/preview" bit was super helpful for my user case.